# table width not adaptive in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

table not displaying full-width in IE Explorer. How to make the table's width not depend on the column width, e.g., 100px*3, but depend on the window width?

CSS Code:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
    </table>
```

Notice that this problem doesn't exist in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: ur code is working fine in IE. Also you have not properly closed your `<tbody>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put width attribute in table with 100%

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">xxx</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
    </table>
```